# Не работает перевод при AJAX запросе. WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На странице "Оформления заказа" ajax возвращает не переведенный блок "Ваш заказ". На скринах все видно. Использую Polylang но думаю он тут не причем, т.к. строки стандартные от woo.

1. http://prntscr.com/iuogvc
2. http://prntscr.com/iuoh2k

Comment: А почему думаете, что тут ajax? А если без него? Какой смысл в двух картинках?

Comment: Те кто сталкивался с Woo знают что таблица Your Order возвращается с помощью ajax, т.к. при выборе оплаты/доставки сумма должна пересчитываться без перезагрузки страницы. И так уж повелось (вопрос к разработчикам) что при заходе на страницу Оформления заказа, сначала отображается первый её вариант с не активным блоком/таблицей заказа (первый скрин - с переведенными строками), а затем тут же содержимое этой таблицы/блока обновляется посредством ajax, но с сервера приходят не переведенные строки (второй скрин).

Comment: Вы бы сразу описали вот это в вопросе, было бы понятно. Да, там идет `?wc-ajax=update_order_review`. Но ни на одном из сайтов с WooCommerce я такого не видел. Правда, я не пользуюсь Polylang. Только WPML с WooCommerce Multilingual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено.
Ответ был все же в Polylang. В настройках убрать галочку с "Hide URL language information for default language".